# Optimization of loops and if

Tags: c++, c, loops, optimization, branch

**I have a procedure looks like this:**

```
void Process1(unsigned char* data)
{

}
void Process2(unsigned char* data)
{

}
void Process3(unsigned char* data)
{

}

#define FLAG1 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG2 (1 << 2)
#define FLAG3 (1 << 3)

void ProcessData(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes, unsigned int flags)
{
    bool b1 = !!(flags & FLAG1);
    bool b2 = !!(flags & FLAG2);
    bool b3 = !!(flags & FLAG3);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
    {
        if (b1) Process1(data + i);
        if (b2) Process2(data + i);
        if (b3) Process3(data + i);
    }
}
```

As it looks, `flags & FLAG1` A.K.A `b1` will not change in all the loops. But we still have to do branch in every loop. I just wondering if there's a way to avoid this unnecessary branch dynamically.

here is a demo of Lundin's solution.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
LARGE_INTEGER ls, le, ll;
#define START_CLOCK() QueryPerformanceCounter(&ls)
#define END_CLOCK() printf ("%.0lf ns\n", (QueryPerformanceCounter(&le), ((double)le.QuadPart - ls.QuadPart) / ll.QuadPart * 1000000));


void Process1(unsigned char* data)
{
    (*data)++;
}
void Process2(unsigned char* data)
{
    (*data)--;
}
void Process3(unsigned char* data)
{
    (*data) *= (*data);
}

#define FLAG1 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG2 (1 << 2)
#define FLAG3 (1 << 3)

void ProcessData(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes, unsigned int flags)
{
    bool b1 = !!(flags & FLAG1);
    bool b2 = !!(flags & FLAG2);
    bool b3 = !!(flags & FLAG3);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
    {
        if (b1) Process1(data + i);
        if (b2) Process2(data + i);
        if (b3) Process3(data + i);
    }
}


typedef void (*proc_t)(unsigned char*);

inline static void do_nothing (unsigned char* ptr)
{
    (void)ptr;
}

void ProcessData_x(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes, unsigned int flags)
{
    bool b1 = (flags & FLAG1) != 0;  // de-obfuscate the boolean logic
    bool b2 = (flags & FLAG2) != 0;
    bool b3 = (flags & FLAG3) != 0;

    proc_t p1 = b1 ? Process1 : do_nothing;
    proc_t p2 = b2 ? Process2 : do_nothing;
    proc_t p3 = b3 ? Process3 : do_nothing;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<bytes; i++)
    {
        p1(data + i);
        p2(data + i);
        p3(data + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&ll)) return 1;

    const unsigned int bytes = 0xffff;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    unsigned int flags = rand() & 0x7;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[bytes];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
    {
        data[i] = (unsigned char)(rand() & 0xff);
    }

    START_CLOCK();

    ProcessData(data, bytes, flags);

    END_CLOCK();

    START_CLOCK();

    ProcessData_x(data, bytes, flags);

    END_CLOCK();
}
```

here is the output:

```
134 ns
272 ns
```

I've run it several times but, unexpectedly, it costs even more time:(.. it is also compiled 'vs2010 Release x86'

Comment: Is the process as simple as additions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't any sense to speak about optimizations without a particular system in mind...

That being said, I'd optimize away the branches in the following way:

```
typedef void (*proc_t)(unsigned char*);

inline static void do_nothing (unsigned char* ptr)
{
    (void)ptr;
}

...

void ProcessData(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes, unsigned int flags)
{
    bool b1 = (flags & FLAG1) != 0;  // de-obfuscate the boolean logic
    bool b2 = (flags & FLAG2) != 0;
    bool b3 = (flags & FLAG3) != 0;

    proc_t p1 = b1 ? Process1 : do_nothing;
    proc_t p2 = b2 ? Process2 : do_nothing;
    proc_t p3 = b3 ? Process3 : do_nothing;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<bytes; i++)
    {
        p1(data + i);
        p2(data + i);
        p3(data + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this solution is good. thank you! btw. is there any way to avoid this `do_nothing` call by `#define`? as i know this function will be 'almost certainly' inlined, i just want this `looks efficient `:D

Comment: Declaring `do_nothing` `inline` probably does nothing, since its address is taken and state of flags is not known at compile time.

Comment: @user694733 you might be right. as i compiled in Release VS2010, the `do_nothing` function is still be `call` in asm.

Comment: @JimYang But there are no branches in loop as per the requirement.

Comment: @JimYang "compiled in Release VS2010"  These kind of optimizations do not make much sense on a PC, it falls under the category of "pre-mature optimization". A few CPU ticks here and there won't matter in the slightest, since a PC already got non-existent real-time performance. Your time is most likely better spent on programming the actual application.

Comment: This is not likely to be an optimization on most systems. If the ProcessN functions are short enough for it to be worth optimizing away the branches then this version is likely slower since they can no longer be inlined. A branch and an inlined call is likely faster than a non inlined call.

Comment: @Lundin maybe the best way is doing nothing? I post a demo test of your implemention and it doesn't work really good:(

Comment: @JimYang Oh, on a PC I would certainly expect this to be slower than what you had to begin with. This would be why my answer started with the sentence "First of all, it doesn't any sense to speak about optimizations without a particular system in mind..."

Answer (score 3):

A c++ solution. Similar to Lundin's answer but without calls to empty function. I'm not sure if that makes any difference in performance, the main advantage is that you don't need to manually list all the process calls in the loop. If you want to micro optimize or want c, you could use an array on stack, but you'll have to manage some counters yourself.

```
typedef void (*proc_t)(unsigned char*);
std::vector<proc_t> processes;
if (b1) processes.push_back(Process1);
if (b2) processes.push_back(Process2);
if (b3) processes.push_back(Process3);

for(auto p : processes)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<bytes; i++)
        p(data + i);
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't think it would be more efficient at this level since another loop it performed.:)

Comment: I agree, this is not likely faster. But I think it's a bit easier to maintain when you have many flags and need to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool b1 = !!(flags & FLAG1);
    bool b2 = !!(flags & FLAG2);
    bool b3 = !!(flags & FLAG3);


    int caseNow=SelectCaseAtOnce(b1,b2,b3);

    if(caseNow==0)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {
            Process1(data + i);

        }
     else if(caseNow==1)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {

           Process2(data + i);

        }
     else if(caseNow==2)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {

             Process3(data + i);
        }
    else if(caseNow==3)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {
            Process1(data + i);
            Process2(data + i);

        }
    if(caseNow==4)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {
             Process1(data + i);

             Process3(data + i);
        }
    else if(caseNow==5)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {

            Process2(data + i);
            Process3(data + i);
        }
    else if(caseNow==6)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i ++)
        {
            Process1(data + i);
            Process2(data + i);
            Process3(data + i);
        }
    else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using templates - this way you'll get an optimized version of the inner loop for each variant. If the ProcessN functions are short / simple enough to be worth inlining then this could be a worthwhile optimization.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

inline void Process1(unsigned char* data) {}
inline void Process2(unsigned char* data) {}
inline void Process3(unsigned char* data) {}

#define FLAG1 (1 << 1)
#define FLAG2 (1 << 2)
#define FLAG3 (1 << 3)

template <bool b1, bool b2, bool b3>
void ProcessData(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        if (b1) Process1(data + i);
        if (b2) Process2(data + i);
        if (b3) Process3(data + i);
    }
}

void ProcessData(unsigned char* data, unsigned int bytes, unsigned int flags) {
    typedef void (*ProcessFunc)(unsigned char*, unsigned int bytes);
    static map<tuple<bool, bool, bool>, ProcessFunc> funcs{
        {make_tuple(false, false, false), ProcessData<false, false, false>},
        {make_tuple(false, false, true), ProcessData<false, false, true>},
        {make_tuple(false, true, false), ProcessData<false, true, false>},
        {make_tuple(false, true, true), ProcessData<false, true, true>},
        {make_tuple(true, false, false), ProcessData<true, false, false>},
        {make_tuple(true, false, true), ProcessData<true, false, true>},
        {make_tuple(true, true, false), ProcessData<true, true, false>},
        {make_tuple(true, true, true), ProcessData<true, true, true>}};

    bool b1 = !!(flags & FLAG1);
    bool b2 = !!(flags & FLAG2);
    bool b3 = !!(flags & FLAG3);
    funcs[make_tuple(b1, b2, b3)](data, bytes);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i don't think this kind of enumeration might help since we may have up to 2^32 cases to list..

Comment: Do you actually need every combination? You could only instantiate the ones that are actually needed (or the most commonly used versions) and then have a fallback to a generic version with branches.